# How can I compare the contribution of two predictors in two different sorts for machine learning algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, r

I'm new to machine learning and try to clarify my problem in research. I just wonder if I can compare the importance of two different variables in two different sorts. For example, A and B are two variables that I want to compare their contribution to ML accuracy. The rest of the variables (like C, D, and E) for each sort are the same.

If I got the results that the rest of the variables (C, D, and E) contributes more (obtain a higher importance score) in the model predicted by A and the rest, can I just say B performs better for ML and its contribution is more significant than the model with A and the rest?

Comment: What kind of model do you plan to use? If you need to measure variable importance I recommend linear regression or decision trees.

Comment: Actually I have already got the variable importance list. Just wondering if I can compare the importance of two variables in two different sorts. Which one is more significant to accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No** you can not.
You are forgeting about variable interactions (C-A,D-A,E-A, etc...)  that could favor A.

You could answer following qestion: If I were to measure information in my variables via variability how would I proceede? For example [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)

The more information you have in the variable(predictor) the higher the chance that it will contribute more to accuracy

Comment: OK, I'll check this later. So does it mean that I can just use statistic methods to identify which one contributes more to accuracy, instead of machine learning?

Comment: a) whats the difference b) Yes, you can just use statistic methods but not only. I gave you an example of how you can make reasonable comparisons c) Accept if this answer satisfies you

Comment: Correct. Those comparisons only hold when the models don’t change